# Why does isset and !isset both return true?

Tags: php

The following block of code prints FOUND and NOT FOUND for each element in the array.  What am I missing?

```
$values = DB::query($SQL);

print_r($values);
foreach($values as $value)
{
    $myVal = $value->thisAttribute;

    if(isset($myVal)) print("FOUND");

    if(!isset($myVal)) print("NOT FOUND");
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [thisAttribute] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [thisAttribute] => value
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [thisAttribute] => 
        )
)    
FOUNDNOTFOUNDFOUNDNOTFOUNDFOUNDNOTFOUND
```

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: On a side note: you should not be checking variables that you know exist with `isset`. You're just unnecessarily suppressing error reporting.

Comment: Answers so far seem okay but they don't actually explain why _both_ strings are being output for each index in the array. Unless the OP is smoking crack of course :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm supporting the crack theory. ;-P

Comment: $myVal is always `set` to whatever thisAttribute is...

Comment: @swiss196 Unless `thisAttribute` is `null`...

Comment: Id throw in a print("next"); line so you can see if they're actually being printed for each element.

Comment: Not smoking crack, both strings print.  Try it yourself.  $values is an associative array returned from a laravel query.

Comment: Well, again, please provide 100% proof that you're not smoking anything. :) How are you 100% certain it prints both every time? There's nothing in your code that proofs exactly that. Throw in a `var_dump($myVal)` there...

Comment: longer example with output

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://3v4l.org/ng0sd

Comment: [CNR](https://xkcd.com/583/). Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I guess the proper way to do that is :

```
foreach($values as $value)
{
  if(isset($value->thisAttribute)) {
    $myVal = $value->thisAttribute;
    print("FOUND");
  } else
    print("NOT FOUND");
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this but why are both being printed each time?